# Will FCM ditch the support of Web Push Protocol?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

As we know, `HTTP legacy API` was deprecated on June 20, 2023, and [will be removed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) in June 2024.

The problem is `HTTP legacy API` and `Web Push Protocol` [are sharing](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/web-push-interop-wins) the same endpoint:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/...
```

I'm worried that disabling `HTTP legacy API` will affect `Web Push Protocol` support. And I can't find the explicit statement about whether `Web Push Protocol` will be affected.

Comment: *firebaser here* Nothing is being changed for web push. I'm asking around if any materials need updating here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There are no currently plans to retire this endpoint **for sending messages to Web Push tokens.**

Google is committed to supporting the open web/standards such as Web Push.